# Set.Attribute before for loop

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain me why I cant declare the `var` node before the for loop? And then just `appendChild(node)` inside the loop? Why do I have to declare it for every iteration, for it to have effect on all div elements? Else it would just add the `textWebinare` to the last element. The Variable is not changed inside my loop so I can't really wrap my head around it.

DOES NOT WORK:

```
<div class="video-container">
test
</div>
<div class="video-container">
test
</div>
<div class="video-container">
test
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var node = document.createElement('div');
        node.setAttribute("id", "textWebinare");
        var video = document.getElementsByClassName("video-container");

        var i;
        for(i = 0; i<video.length; i++){
            video[i].appendChild(node);   
        }
    });
</script>
```

DOES WORK:

```
<div class="video-container">
test
</div>
<div class="video-container">
test
</div>
<div class="video-container">
test
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var video = document.getElementsByClassName("video-container");

        var i;
        for(i = 0; i<video.length; i++){
        var node = document.createElement('div');
        node.setAttribute("id", "textWebinare");
            video[i].appendChild(node);   
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In the first example there's only one `<div>` (stored in `node`), so you're appending the same node again and again in a `.video-container`. The second example creates a new `<div>` for every `.video-container`

Comment: Further, it's worth noting that you're creating invalid HTML since you're assigning the same `id` to various elements (or the same element repeatedly).

Comment: *"why i cant declare the var node before the for loop"* You can. But you can't **create** the node (`createElement`) before the loop (or rather, if you do, you just move the element repeatedly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `document.createElement('div')` to be like creating *a car*.

Then consider `video[i]` to be a parking space and `appendChild(node)` to be parking a car in that space.

If you create one car, and then park it in a three of parking spaces in sequence then you'll end up with one car in the last space, not a car in each of three spaces.

If you want a car in each space then you'll need to create three cars.

---

A single div can't be in multiple parts of the same HTML document at the same time.

Comment: Ah. so im not creating a a variable a variable <div id="textWebinare> . im creating a actual element just one time. (createElement could have been a hint to me :D). Your car explenation was spot on, i really understood it now. Thank you so much.